# Get routerLink properties from HTML in Angular unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-test

I have following HTML property:

```
   <ul>   
      <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I want now to get the href as a value in the unit test. So far I have in my test-case:

```
  it('should navigate have login navigation', () => {
     const debugElements = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('a.nav-link'));
     debugElements.forEach(x  => console.log(x.properties['href']));
  });
});
```

But that is every time `undefined`. How do I fetch the href from the rounterLink directive? Incidentally, I don't need to do `fixture.detectChanges();` Since I don't use lifecycle-hooks in this particular comp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have to run `fixture.detectChanges()`. This is not limited to lifecycle hooks but concerns change detection in general (so pretty much any *magic* that Angular does).

I've created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-jr9pjv?file=app/app.component.spec.ts) demonstrating that the test is failing without `detectChanges` and running with it.

Comment: What a freaking mess. I was sitting there for 3 hours just thinking detectChanges can not be the reason of my failure, until someone says: 'Yeah u need detectChanges!'.^^